# Reducing virtual memory makes the database not available

Tags: postgresql

Windows server 2008. PostgreSQL 9.6. RAM 12 GB.
Last uptime was 1 year.
In the system virtual memory was set to automatic mode and grew to 28 GB.
There was a need to reduce the size of virtual memory to 4 GB. The server has rebooted and the virtual memory has been reduced.
At night, the database becomes unavailable.

The line repeats in the logs:
`EET LOG: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding`

Restarting the server restores access to the database.
The next night everything repeats, and so on.

After increasing the virtual memory to 32GB, everything returned to normal.

The main questions are: why is this happening and how to reduce the size of virtual memory without negative consequences?

```
2023-03-18 02:30:21 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:30:42 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:30:52 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:31:03 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:31:13 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:31:22 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:31:29 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:31:29 EET STATEMENT:  /*pga4dash*/
    SELECT 'session_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity) AS "Total",
       (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active')  AS "Active",
       (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'idle')  AS "Idle"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'tps_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(xact_commit) + sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Transactions",
       (SELECT sum(xact_commit) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Commits",
       (SELECT sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Rollbacks"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ti_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(tup_inserted) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Inserts",
       (SELECT sum(tup_updated) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Updates",
       (SELECT sum(tup_deleted) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Deletes"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'to_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(tup_fetched) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Fetched",
       (SELECT sum(tup_returned) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Returned"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bio_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(blks_read) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Reads",
       (SELECT sum(blks_hit) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Hits"
    ) t
    
2023-03-18 02:31:33 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:31:42 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:31:53 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:32:03 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:32:14 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:32:22 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:32:30 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:32:30 EET STATEMENT:  /*pga4dash*/
    SELECT 'session_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
...

2023-03-18 02:32:33 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:32:42 EET LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-03-18 02:32:42 EET LOG:  CreateProcess call failed: unrecognized winsock error 10004 (error code 8)
2023-03-18 02:32:42 EET LOG:  could not fork autovacuum worker process: No error
2023-03-18 02:32:43 EET LOG:  CreateProcess call failed: unrecognized winsock error 10004 (error code 8)
2023-03-18 02:32:43 EET LOG:  could not fork autovacuum worker process: No error
2023-03-18 02:32:44 EET LOG:  CreateProcess call failed: unrecognized winsock error 10004 (error code 8)
2023-03-18 02:32:44 EET LOG:  could not fork autovacuum worker process: No error
TopMemoryContext: 222960 total in 9 blocks; 64368 free (106 chunks); 158592 used
  TopTransactionContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7968 free (0 chunks); 224 used
  TableSpace cache: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 2320 free (0 chunks); 5872 used
  Record information cache: 24576 total in 2 blocks; 15088 free (5 chunks); 9488 used
  Operator lookup cache: 24576 total in 2 blocks; 10992 free (5 chunks); 13584 used
  MessageContext: 131072 total in 5 blocks; 1080 free (1 chunks); 129992 used
  Operator class cache: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 784 free (0 chunks); 7408 used
  smgr relation table: 24576 total in 2 blocks; 8912 free (4 chunks); 15664 used
  TransactionAbortContext: 32768 total in 1 blocks; 32736 free (0 chunks); 32 used
  Portal hash: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 784 free (0 chunks); 7408 used
  PortalMemory: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 8160 free (1 chunks); 32 used
  Relcache by OID: 24576 total in 2 blocks; 12976 free (4 chunks); 11600 used
  CacheMemoryContext: 1040384 total in 7 blocks; 513304 free (0 chunks); 527080 used
    pg_stat_database: 15360 total in 4 blocks; 760 free (0 chunks); 14600 used
    pg_stat_activity: 23552 total in 5 blocks; 6504 free (0 chunks); 17048 used
    pg_toast_2618_index: 1024 total in 1 blocks; 272 free (0 chunks); 752 used
    pg_roles: 15360 total in 4 blocks; 1392 free (0 chunks); 13968 used
    pg_index_indrelid_index: 1024 total in 1 blocks; 408 free (0 chunks); 616 used
...
    pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index: 1024 total in 1 blocks; 272 free (0 chunks); 752 used
    pg_class_oid_index: 1024 total in 1 blocks; 408 free (0 chunks); 616 used
  WAL record construction: 49760 total in 2 blocks; 6592 free (0 chunks); 43168 used
  PrivateRefCount: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 2848 free (0 chunks); 5344 used
  MdSmgr: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 6656 free (0 chunks); 1536 used
  LOCALLOCK hash: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 784 free (0 chunks); 7408 used
  Timezones: 104112 total in 2 blocks; 2848 free (0 chunks); 101264 used
  ErrorContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 8160 free (3 chunks); 32 used
Grand total: 1914880 bytes in 137 blocks; 752616 free (135 chunks); 1162264 used
2023-03-18 02:33:18 EET ERROR:  out of memory
2023-03-18 02:33:18 EET DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 16.
2023-03-18 02:33:18 EET STATEMENT:  /*pga4dash*/
    SELECT 'session_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity) AS "Total",
       (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active')  AS "Active",
       (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'idle')  AS "Idle"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'tps_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(xact_commit) + sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Transactions",
       (SELECT sum(xact_commit) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Commits",
       (SELECT sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Rollbacks"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ti_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(tup_inserted) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Inserts",
       (SELECT sum(tup_updated) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Updates",
       (SELECT sum(tup_deleted) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Deletes"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'to_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(tup_fetched) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Fetched",
       (SELECT sum(tup_returned) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Returned"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bio_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(blks_read) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Reads",
       (SELECT sum(blks_hit) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Hits"
    ) t
    
2023-03-18 02:33:52 EET WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled
2023-03-18 02:34:52 EET WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled
2023-03-18 02:35:08 EET ERROR:  GEOSBuffer: std::bad_alloc
2023-03-18 02:35:08 EET STATEMENT:  FETCH 500 in OGRPGLayerReader000000000182EC10
2023-03-18 02:35:08 EET ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
2023-03-18 02:35:08 EET STATEMENT:  CLOSE OGRPGLayerReader000000000182EC10
2023-03-18 02:35:52 EET WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled
2023-03-18 02:36:52 EET WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled
2023-03-18 02:37:52 EET WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled
2023-03-18 02:38:52 EET WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled
...
2023-03-18 10:34:12 EET ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
```

Comment: You probably increased `shared_buffers` or `work_mem` to an insanely high value. Btw: neither Windows Server 2008 nor Postgres 9.6 are supported. You should really plan an upgrade now.

Comment: seems, default values: shared_buffers = 512MB, work_mem = 345kB. Yes, an update is planned.

Comment: Were there other messages in the logs?  That one doesn't seem very informative.  It is probably just the symptom of some other problem, not the cause of the problem.

Comment: I added the contents of one of the files that was created the next day after changing the virtual memory at 00:00 AM